# create a dropdown using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

here's my json in the form of map
{
 "Area1": [
  "Office1",
  "office2"
 ]
}

I want to create 2 dropdown using ng-repeat in angularjs, i.e area1 in one dropdown and office_1 and office_2 in another dropdown. But I am not available to achieve this.can somebody help

Comment: Give your tried code in plunker

Comment: <div class="col-xs-6">
  <h5>Select the area:</h5>

  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="system in systems.area1">{{system}}</option>
  </select>


</div>
</div>

Comment: here's the plunker code
http://plnkr.co/edit/ID6k7BJ9KppfzNOktpi2?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, where model is your office map json model :

```
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedArea">
      <option ng-repeat="(key,prop) in model" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="repeatSelect1" ng-model="selectedState">
      <option ng-repeat="state in model[selectedArea]" value="state">{{state}}</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you help me in changing the size of the drop down..i want each dropdown to cover the entire screen width.@curiousgeek